# White Balance a photo from a known point

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, colors, opencv3.0

White Balancing is a rather well-covered topic, but most of the answers I have seen cover automatic white balancing techniques for an entire image that does not have a known point for what is white, gray, and black. I cannot seem to find many that cover white balancing from a known point. I have the script (below) that takes an image of a color card (Spyder Checkr 48) and returns the white, 20% Gray, and Black color card blocks:

```
Color       L      A     B     sR   sG   sB   aR   aG   aB
Card White  96.04  2.16  2.6   249  242  238  247  242  237
20% Gray    80.44  1.17  2.05  202  198  195  199  196  193
Card Black  16.91  1.43  -0.81 43   41   43   46   46   47
```

**Question:** Since I know the ground truth LAB, sRGB and AdobeRGB values for specific parts of the image, what would be the best way to white balance the image?

[Here is a link to the images I am working with.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DVSPXk2Mbj8jpAU2EeZfK8d2HZM9taiH?usp=sharing) This is the code for extracting the color card blocks (I currently am running this on Windows, Python 3.7):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import sys

image = cv2.imread("PATH_TO_IMAGE")
template = cv2.imread("PATH_TO_TEMPLATE")
rtemplate = cv2.imread("PATH_TO_RIGHT_TEMPLATE")


def sift(image):
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(image, None)
    return kp, des

def sift_match(im1, im2, vis=False, save=False):
    MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
    FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
    kp1, des1 = sift(im1)
    kp2, des2 = sift(im2)

    index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=7)

    search_params = dict(checks=100)

    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

    # Need to draw only good matches, so create a mask
    matchesMask = [[0, 0] for i in range(len(matches))]

    if vis is True:
        draw_params = dict(matchColor=(0, 255, 0),
                           singlePointColor=(255, 0, 0),
                           matchesMask=matchesMask,
                           flags=0)

        im3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(im1, kp1, im2, kp2, matches, None, **draw_params)

        if save:
            cv2.imwrite("tempSIFT_Match.png", im3)

        plt.imshow(im3), plt.show()
    good = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
            good.append(m)
    return kp1, des1, kp2, des2, good



def smartextractor(im1, im2, vis=False):

    # Detect features and compute descriptors.
    kp1, d1, kp2, d2, matches = sift_match(im1, im2, vis)
    kp1 = np.asarray(kp1)
    kp2 = np.asarray(kp2)

    # Extract location of good matches
    points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

    for i, match in enumerate(matches):
        points1[i, :] = kp1[match.queryIdx].pt
        points2[i, :] = kp2[match.trainIdx].pt

    # Find homography
    h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)

    if h is None:
        print("could not find homography")
        return None, None

    # Use homography
    height, width, channels = im2.shape
    im1Reg = cv2.warpPerspective(im1, h, (width, height))

    return im1Reg, h


def show_images(images, cols=1, titles=None):
    """
    Display a list of images in a single figure with matplotlib.
    """
    assert ((titles is None) or (len(images) == len(titles)))
    n_images = len(images)
    if titles is None: titles = ['Image (%d)' % i for i in range(1, n_images + 1)]
    fig = plt.figure()
    for n, (image, title) in enumerate(zip(images, titles)):
        a = fig.add_subplot(cols, np.ceil(n_images / float(cols)), n + 1)
        if image.ndim == 2:
            plt.gray()
        plt.imshow(image)
        a.set_title(title)
    fig.set_size_inches(np.array(fig.get_size_inches()) * n_images)
    plt.show()


def Sobel(img, bilateralFilter=True):
    # timestart = time.clock()
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(img, 0)
    except TypeError:
        None
    try:
        rheight, rwidth, rdepth = img.shape
        img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    except ValueError:
        raise TypeError
    # cv2.imwrite('temp.png',img)
    _, s, v = cv2.split(img1)
    b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
    if bilateralFilter is True:
        s = cv2.bilateralFilter(s, 11, 17, 17)
        v = cv2.bilateralFilter(v, 11, 17, 17)
        b = cv2.bilateralFilter(b, 11, 17, 17)
        g = cv2.bilateralFilter(g, 11, 17, 17)
        r = cv2.bilateralFilter(r, 11, 17, 17)
    # calculate sobel in x,y,diagonal directions with the following kernels
    sobelx = np.array([[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)
    sobely = np.array([[-1, -2, -1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1]], dtype=np.float32)
    sobeldl = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [-1, 0, 1], [-2, -1, 0]], dtype=np.float32)
    sobeldr = np.array([[2, 1, 0], [1, 0, -1], [0, -1, -2]], dtype=np.float32)
    # calculate the sobel on value of hsv
    gx = cv2.filter2D(v, -1, sobelx)
    gy = cv2.filter2D(v, -1, sobely)
    gdl = cv2.filter2D(v, -1, sobeldl)
    gdr = cv2.filter2D(v, -1, sobeldr)
    # combine sobel on value of hsv
    xylrv = 0.25 * gx + 0.25 * gy + 0.25 * gdl + 0.25 * gdr

    # calculate the sobel on saturation of hsv
    sx = cv2.filter2D(s, -1, sobelx)
    sy = cv2.filter2D(s, -1, sobely)
    sdl = cv2.filter2D(s, -1, sobeldl)
    sdr = cv2.filter2D(s, -1, sobeldr)
    # combine sobel on value of hsv
    xylrs = 0.25 * sx + 0.25 * sy + 0.25 * sdl + 0.25 * sdr

    # combine value sobel and saturation sobel
    xylrc = 0.5 * xylrv + 0.5 * xylrs
    xylrc[xylrc < 6] = 0

    # calculate the sobel on value on green
    grx = cv2.filter2D(g, -1, sobelx)
    gry = cv2.filter2D(g, -1, sobely)
    grdl = cv2.filter2D(g, -1, sobeldl)
    grdr = cv2.filter2D(g, -1, sobeldr)
    # combine sobel on value on green
    xylrgr = 0.25 * grx + 0.25 * gry + 0.25 * grdl + 0.25 * grdr

    # calculate the sobel on blue
    bx = cv2.filter2D(b, -1, sobelx)
    by = cv2.filter2D(b, -1, sobely)
    bdl = cv2.filter2D(b, -1, sobeldl)
    bdr = cv2.filter2D(b, -1, sobeldr)
    # combine sobel on value on blue
    xylrb = 0.25 * bx + 0.25 * by + 0.25 * bdl + 0.25 * bdr

    # calculate the sobel on red
    rx = cv2.filter2D(r, -1, sobelx)
    ry = cv2.filter2D(r, -1, sobely)
    rdl = cv2.filter2D(r, -1, sobeldl)
    rdr = cv2.filter2D(r, -1, sobeldr)
    # combine sobel on value on red
    xylrr = 0.25 * rx + 0.25 * ry + 0.25 * rdl + 0.25 * rdr

    # combine value sobel and saturation sobel
    xylrrgb = 0.33 * xylrgr + 0.33 * xylrb + 0.33 * xylrr
    xylrrgb[xylrrgb < 6] = 0

    # combine HSV and RGB sobel outputs
    xylrc = 0.5 * xylrc + 0.5 * xylrrgb
    xylrc[xylrc < 6] = 0
    xylrc[xylrc > 25] = 255

    return xylrc

print("extracting image")
extractedImage, _ = smartextractor(image, template)

print("extracting right image")
rextractedImage, _ = smartextractor(extractedImage, rtemplate, vis=False)
grextractedImage = cv2.cvtColor(rextractedImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bfsobelImg = Sobel(rextractedImage)
sobelImg = Sobel(rextractedImage, bilateralFilter=False)
csobelImg = cv2.add(bfsobelImg, sobelImg)
csobelImg[csobelImg < 6] = 0
csobelImg[csobelImg > 18] = 255

csobelImg = csobelImg.astype(np.uint8)
img2 = csobelImg.copy()
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img2, 18, 255, 0)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)



count = 0
trigger = False
for c in contours:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    contours[count] = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)

    if len(contours[count]) == 4:
        if trigger is False:
            screenCnt = contours[count]
            trigger = True

    count += 1

tl = screenCnt[0]
tr = screenCnt[1]
bl = screenCnt[3]
br = screenCnt[2]

tLy, tLx = tl[0]
tRy, tRx = tr[0]
bLy, bLx = bl[0]
bRy, bRx = br[0]

ratio = .15
realSpace = (3/16)
boxwidth = int(((tRx - tLx) + (bRx - bLx))*.5 - (tLx + bLx)*.5)
boxheight = int(((bRy - tRy) + (bLy - tLy))*.5 - (tRy + tLy)*.5)
spaceWidth = int((boxwidth + boxheight)*.5*realSpace)
boxcenter = [int(((bRy - tRy)*.5 + (bLy - tLy)*.5)*.5), int(((tRx - tLx)*.5 + (bRx - bLx)*.5)*.5)]
roitl = [boxcenter[0] - int(ratio*boxheight), boxcenter[1] - int(ratio*boxwidth)]
roitr = [boxcenter[0] - int(ratio*boxheight), boxcenter[1] + int(ratio*boxwidth)]
roibl = [boxcenter[0] + int(ratio*boxheight), boxcenter[1] - int(ratio*boxwidth)]
roibr = [boxcenter[0] + int(ratio*boxheight), boxcenter[1] + int(ratio*boxwidth)]

spacing = int((boxwidth + boxheight)*.5)+spaceWidth
roiWhite = np.array((roitl, roitr, roibr, roibl))


roiGray = np.array(([roitl[1], roitl[0]+spacing*1], [roitr[1], roitr[0]+spacing*1],
                    [roibr[1], roibr[0]+spacing*1], [roibl[1], roibl[0]+spacing*1]))

roiBlack = np.array(([roitl[1], roitl[0]+spacing*6], [roitr[1], roitr[0]+spacing*6],
                     [roibr[1], roibr[0]+spacing*6], [roibl[1], roibl[0]+spacing*6]))

whiteAvgb, whiteAvgg, whiteAvgr, _ = cv2.mean(rextractedImage[(roitl[0]+spacing*0):(roibr[0]+spacing*0),
                                              roitl[1]:roibr[1]])
grayAvgb, grayAvgg, grayAvgr, _ = cv2.mean(rextractedImage[(roitl[0]+spacing*1):(roibr[0]+spacing*1),
                                           roitl[1]:roibr[1]])
blackAvgb, blackAvgg, blackAvgr, _ = cv2.mean(rextractedImage[(roitl[0]+spacing*6):(roibr[0]+spacing*6),
                                              roitl[1]:roibr[1]])

whiteROI = rextractedImage[(roitl[0]+spacing*0):(roibr[0]+spacing*0), roitl[1]:roibr[1]]
grayROI = rextractedImage[(roitl[0]+spacing*1):(roibr[0]+spacing*1), roitl[1]:roibr[1]]
blackROI = rextractedImage[(roitl[0]+spacing*6):(roibr[0]+spacing*6), roitl[1]:roibr[1]]
imageList = [whiteROI, grayROI, blackROI]
show_images(imageList, cols=1)

correctedImage = rextractedImage.copy()

whiteROI[:, :, 0] = whiteAvgb
whiteROI[:, :, 1] = whiteAvgg
whiteROI[:, :, 2] = whiteAvgr

grayROI[:, :, 0] = grayAvgb
grayROI[:, :, 1] = grayAvgg
grayROI[:, :, 2] = grayAvgr

blackROI[:, :, 0] = blackAvgb
blackROI[:, :, 1] = blackAvgg
blackROI[:, :, 2] = blackAvgr

imageList = [whiteROI, grayROI, blackROI]
show_images(imageList, cols=1)

# SPYDER COLOR CHECKR Values: http://www.bartneck.de/2017/10/24/patch-color-definitions-for-datacolor-spydercheckr-48/

blank = np.zeros_like(csobelImg)
maskedImg = blank.copy()
maskedImg = cv2.fillConvexPoly(maskedImg, roiWhite, 255)
maskedImg = cv2.fillConvexPoly(maskedImg, roiGray, 255)
maskedImg = cv2.fillConvexPoly(maskedImg, roiBlack, 255)

res = cv2.bitwise_and(rextractedImage, rextractedImage, mask=maskedImg)
# maskedImg = cv2.fillConvexPoly(maskedImg, roi2Black, 255)

cv2.drawContours(blank, contours, -1, 255, 3)

outputSquare = np.zeros_like(csobelImg)
cv2.drawContours(outputSquare, [screenCnt], -1, 255, 3)

imageList = [rextractedImage, grextractedImage, bfsobelImg, sobelImg, csobelImg, blank, outputSquare, maskedImg, res]
show_images(imageList, cols=3)

sys.exit()
```

Comment: You shouldn't use Sobel in 4 directions. 2 suffice. Combine the results using `sqrt(gx**2+gy**2)`. That will give you a more isotropic result than what you're doing now, at a reduced computational cost.

Comment: Are you looking to do a full color correction, or just white balancing?

Comment: Noted on the Sobel's. I'm not worried about speed, just trying new things is all. A full-color correction would be great! But I would settle for just white balancing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the RGB value of a white patch, the image can be corrected for white balance by dividing by that value. That is, applying a linear transformation that makes the white patch have the same level in the three channels:

```
lum = (whiteR + whiteG + whiteB)/3
imgR = imgR * lum / whiteR
imgG = imgG * lum / whiteG
imgB = imgB * lum / whiteB
```

Multiplying by `lum` makes it so that the average intensity doesn’t change.

(The computation of `lum` will be better if using proper weights: 0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, but I wanted to keep it simple. This would only make a big difference if the input white is way off the mark, in which case you'll have other issues too.)

**Note** that this transformation is best applied in linear RGB space. Both the image and the RGB values for white should first be converted to linear RGB if the image is stored in sRGB or similar (a raw image from the camera would be linear RGB, a JPEG would be sRGB). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation) for the relevant equations.

For better precision, you can apply the above using also the RGB values of the grey patch. Take the average multiplication factor (`whiteR/lum`) derived from the white and grey patches, for each channel, and apply those to the image.

The black level could be subtracted from the image, prior to determining the white RGB values and correcting for white balance. This will improve contrast and color perception, but not part of white balancing.

A full color correction is way more complex, I will not go into that.

Comment: To anyone reading this have a look at "colour-science" for python. It is an incredible python library for everything color related! https://github.com/colour-science/colour

Comment: @Cris Luengo, what would be a starting point for full color correction

Comment: @pratiklodha: you need a color chart, and know the expected RGB value for each patch. You then determine a map from input RGB to corrected RGB, where you interpolate in between the pairs that you measured in your patch. This map you can then just look up any input RGB value to decide a corrected output color.  Each of those steps has some nuances I’m skipping over. I honestly would go with an existing commercial solution.