# How to locate and extract a maze from a photo without being sensitive to warp or light

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have been asking several questions for locating and extracting maze from photos on SOF,
but none of the answers I get work across different photos, not even across 4 testing photos.
Every time when I tweaked the code to make it work for 1 photo, it will fail on the rest of photos due to warped corners/parts or light etc. I feel that I need to find a way which is insensitive to warped image and different intensity of light or the different colors of maze walls(the lines inside a maze).

I have been trying to make it work for 3 weeks without a luck. Before I drop the idea, I would like to ask is it possible to just use Image Processing without AI to locate and extract a maze from a photo? If yes, could you please show me how to do it?

Here are the code and photos:

```
import cv2    
import numpy as np

from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity
from skimage.feature import corner_harris, corner_subpix, corner_peaks
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
from skimage.morphology import reconstruction, binary_erosion, skeletonize, dilation, square
from skimage.morphology.convex_hull import convex_hull_image
from skimage.util import invert
from skmpe import parameters, mpe, OdeSolverMethod

maze=cv2.imread("simple.jpg",0)
ret, maze=cv2.threshold(maze,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
h, w = maze.shape
seed = np.zeros_like(maze)
size = 40
hh = h // 2
hw = w // 2
seed[hh-size:hh+size, hw-size:hw+size] = maze[hh-size:hh+size, hw-size:hw+size]
rec1 = reconstruction(seed, maze)
seed2 = np.ones_like(rec1)
ker = np.ones((2,2))
rec1_thicker = cv2.erode(rec1, ker, iterations=1)    

seed2 = seed2 * 255
size2 = 240
lhh = hh - size2
hhh = hh + size2
lhw = hw - size2
hhw = hw + size2
seed2[lhh:hhh, lhw:hhw]=rec1_thicker[lhh:hhh, lhw:hhw]
rec2 = reconstruction(seed2,rec1_thicker, method='erosion')
rec2_inv = invert(rec2 / 255.)
hull = convex_hull_image(rec2_inv)
hull_eroded = binary_erosion(hull, selem=np.ones((5,5)))
coords = corner_peaks(corner_harris(hull_eroded), min_distance=5, threshold_rel=0.02)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axe = plt.subplots(1,4,figsize=(16,8))
axe[0].imshow(maze, 'gray')
axe[1].imshow(rec1, 'gray')
axe[2].imshow(rec2, 'gray')
axe[3].imshow(hull, 'gray')
```

Here is the output image:
[image]

As you can see that the 3rd plot is the extracted maze, this piece of code works well, but just for this 2 photos, in this case they are `simple.jpg` and 'maze.jpg'...

if you tried the `hard.jpg' then it looks like this:
[image]

and it also fails on the `middle.jpg`:
[image]

I have uploaded all 4 testing photos to [OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asflam6BEzhjgbIh8_tQqdv-V4RBgA?e=3nYbg6) for anyone who is interested to try them out.

---

Update 1

I plotted all masks to see what each one of them does.

```
mask = (sat < 16).astype(np.uint8) * 255
mask1 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (31, 31)))
mask2 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(mask1, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 0)
mask3 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (201, 201)))

plt.figure(figsize=(18, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 6, 1), plt.imshow(maze[..., ::-1]), plt.title('White balanced image')
plt.subplot(1, 6, 2), plt.imshow(sat, 'gray'), plt.title('Saturation channel')
plt.subplot(1, 6, 3), plt.imshow(mask, 'gray'), plt.title('sat < 16')
plt.subplot(1, 6, 4), plt.imshow(mask1, 'gray'), plt.title('closed')
plt.subplot(1, 6, 5), plt.imshow(mask2, 'gray'), plt.title('border')
plt.subplot(1, 6, 6), plt.imshow(mask3, 'gray'), plt.title('rect')
plt.tight_layout(), plt.show()
```

[image]

So it seems to me that the mask2 which is making a border around the entire image, is not necessary.
Why do we need the mask2?

I also found that the resolution of mask2 and mask3 are 2 pixels bigger in each dimensions:

```
maze.shape, sat.shape, mask.shape, mask1.shape, mask2.shape, mask3.shape
((4000, 1840, 3),
 (4000, 1840),
 (4000, 1840),
 (4000, 1840),
 (4002, 1842),
 (4002, 1842))
```

Why?

Comment: The mazes seem to be always the region of most high frequencies in the image. Maybe you can use this as basis for a location algorithm...

Comment: hi @stateMachine thanks for your idea. Could you please elaborate your idea? The current code does focus on the central part of the image as you see the code gets a part of image from the photo's central. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really want to get these $ 6.9 dishes, he?

---

For the four given images, I could get quite good results using the following workflow:

- [White balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_balance) the input image to enforce nearly white paper. I took [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54481969/11089932) using a small patch from the center of the image, and from that patch, I took the pixel with the highest `R + G + B` value – assuming the maze is always centered in the image, and there are some pixels from the white paper within the small patch.
- Use the saturation channel from the [HSV color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) to mask the white paper, and (roughly) crop that portion from the image.
- On that crop, perform the existing `reconstruction` approach.

Here are the results:

`maze.jpg`

[image: Maze]

`simple.jpg`

[image: Simple]

`middle.jpg`

[image: Middle]

`hard.jpg`

[image: Hard]

That's the full code:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import binary_erosion, reconstruction
from skimage.morphology.convex_hull import convex_hull_image


# https://stackoverflow.com/a/54481969/11089932
def simple_white_balancing(image):
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    patch = image[int(h/2-20):int(h/2+20), int(w/2-20):int(w/2+20)]
    x, y = cv2.minMaxLoc(np.sum(patch.astype(int), axis=2))[3]
    white_b, white_g, white_r = patch[y, x, ...].astype(float)
    lum = (white_r + white_g + white_b) / 3
    image[..., 0] = image[..., 0] * lum / white_b
    image[..., 1] = image[..., 1] * lum / white_g
    image[..., 2] = image[..., 2] * lum / white_r
    return image


for file in ['maze.jpg', 'simple.jpg', 'middle.jpg', 'hard.jpg']:

    # Read image
    img = cv2.imread(file)

    # Initialize hull image
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    hull = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

    # Simple white balancing, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54481969/11089932
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (11, 11), None)
    maze = simple_white_balancing(img.copy())

    # Mask low saturation area
    sat = cv2.cvtColor(maze, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[..., 1]
    mask = (sat < 16).astype(np.uint8) * 255
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,
                            cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,
                                                      (31, 31)))
    mask = cv2.copyMakeBorder(mask, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 0)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN,
                            cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,
                                                      (201, 201)))

    # Find largest contour in mask (w.r.t. the OpenCV version)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    cnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

    # Crop to low saturation area
    cut = cv2.cvtColor(maze[y+1:y+1+h, x+1:x+1+w], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Use existing reconstruction approach on low saturation area
    h_c, w_c = cut.shape
    seed = np.zeros_like(cut)
    size = 40
    hh = h_c // 2
    hw = w_c // 2
    seed[hh-size:hh+size, hw-size:hw+size] = cut[hh-size:hh+size, hw-size:hw+size]
    rec = reconstruction(seed, cut)
    rec = cv2.erode(rec, np.ones((2, 2)), iterations=1)

    seed = np.ones_like(rec) * 255
    size = 240
    seed[hh-size:hh+size, hw-size:hw+size] = rec[hh-size:hh+size, hw-size:hw+size]
    rec = reconstruction(seed, rec, method='erosion').astype(np.uint8)
    rec = cv2.threshold(rec, np.quantile(rec, 0.25), 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

    hull[y+1:y+1+h, x+1:x+1+w] = convex_hull_image(rec) * 255

    plt.figure(figsize=(18, 8))
    plt.subplot(1, 5, 1), plt.imshow(img[..., ::-1]), plt.title('Original image')
    plt.subplot(1, 5, 2), plt.imshow(maze[..., ::-1]), plt.title('White balanced image')
    plt.subplot(1, 5, 3), plt.imshow(sat, 'gray'), plt.title('Saturation channel')
    plt.subplot(1, 5, 4), plt.imshow(hull, 'gray'), plt.title('Obtained convex hull')
    plt.subplot(1, 5, 5), plt.imshow(cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=hull)[..., ::-1])
    plt.tight_layout(), plt.savefig(file + 'output.png'), plt.show()
```

Of course, there's no guarantee, that this approach will work for the next five images or so, you work on. In general, try to standardize the image acquisition (rotation, lighting) to get more consistent images. Otherwise, you'll end up needing some machine learning approach...

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
Matplotlib:    3.4.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
OpenCV:        4.5.1
scikit-image:  0.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Wow ~! Excellent~!! hahaha yes, my curiosity drives me to see whether it's possible to get the free $6.9 dish hahaha. Thank you so much man! So I guess I missed the `White Balancing` step which behaves like Normalization before doing any image processing. After reading your code, here are my questions:  1. Why do you need to do a `GaussianBlur()` before white balancing? 2. Why do you only * 255 for values less than 16 in the sat mask? How did you get the value 16?

Comment: 1) You don't need Gaussian blurring for the white balancing. I just introduced that as an additional pre-processing step. Sorry for the inaccuracy in the corresponding comment. The blurring just makes the lines of the maze smoother, which is beneficial later. 2) The saturation of `16` was "empirically found", i.e. try-and-error. `(sat < 16)` is just (binary) masking all parts with saturation lower `16`, i.e. you get `True` values; converted to `np.uint8`, that's `1`, but we need `255` in binary masks when dealing with `np.uint8`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. As you said the Gaussian Blur is beneficial later. Could you please elaborate it more? Sorry as a beginner, I only saw these terms but don't know what the uses of these pre-processing steps.

Comment: The main reason why the code can successfully detect the maze(+paper) area is because of the `(sat < 16)` right?

Comment: hi @HansHirse, I have also updated my questions, could you please have a look? I'm happy to make a new question post if you think it's not relevant. thanks